# SELECCIONAR UNA CELDA DE GRIDVIEW EN ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como podria seleccionar solo una celda del gridview en asp.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
     e.Row.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "this.style.cursor = 'pointer' ");
     e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(gv_bus, "select$"+e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
}
```

encontre este codigo solo selecciona toda la fila. me gustaria saber la columna y la fila.

Comment: ese codigo esta adjuntando javascript que ejecuta del lado del cliente, que es lo que quieres lograr con la seleccion ? porque podrias poner un link que ejecute en evento al servidor si quieres trabajar con el dato seleccionado